# Grammar: Is it correct to say 'irresistible to click'?

Tags: grammar

I want to convey that the marketing strategy of a particular website was highly successful because

> they always seem to email links which were ***irresistible*** to click on..

Is it a correct way of saying it?

Comment: You might say "...to email links that recipients couldn't resist clicking."

Comment: "Irresistible" seems out of place for your context (involving e-mail). Perhaps you should replace it with "tempting"... as in.. "*Their marketing campaign was a huge success. Most of their emails with hyperlinks were too tempting*!"

Comment: Maybe you could say the links were *click-worthy*.

Comment: The links were *enticing*.

Comment: If familiar and mildly disparaging language is permitted in your sentence, you could capture the whole idea of “links … irresistible to click on” with “expertly crafted [clickbait](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296797/what-is-the-offline-equivalent-of-clickbait)   (or [click bait](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210357/is-click-bait-an-internet-buzzword-how-can-i-rephrase-it) ”: “… highly successful because of the expertly crafted clickbait contained in their emails.”

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd read better if you stop at "irresistible":

"...they always seem to email links which are irresistible."

(that "were" doesn't fit with "seem to email" so I fixed it, too)

Navigating a link is implicit in what it is, much like an offer or proposition; you don't actually need to explain that links are selected, clicked on, or navigated.

"Compelling" (the email made me do it!) and "tempting" or "inticing" (it looked so interesting, sitting there, all linky) might serve, too.

To overtly answer the title question: "irresistible" describes the noun,  so "irresistible to click on" isn't quite correct but is going to be understood. "...irresistible to click." also works and reads slightly better, to me.
(If I could remember my English lessons, I suppose I could explain that more formally)

In your construction, "irresistible to" tends to denote that what follows is the group that finds the thing irresistible rather than what can't be resisted. ("...links that are irresistible to women.", say)